# Any advice on how to pray at work?

Tags: salat

At work I do not have a designated prayer location. What I did was to proceed to the nearest fireman stairways to pray. But the stairways was dirty and full of cobwebs. I tried searching for other places but there isn't anywhere else. I checked with my Muslim colleagues, they mentioned they pray at the stairways as well. Eventually, I took wudu and prayed standing with my shoes on.

Are my prayers considered void?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you couldn't find any clean place to pray at, you can pray at stairways unless it has 'Najasah' impurity. And using a prayer rug, I think that would be helpful.
And about praying with your shoes on, you sure can. 'Abe Salamah Sa'eed bin Yazeed' said: that Mohammad (صلى الله عليه وسلم) was praying with his shoes on sometimes and without them sometimes.

> فالصلاة بالنعال جائزة، وقد كان صلى الله عليه وسلم يصلي أحياناً حافياً،
>   وأحيانا منتعلاً، ففي الصحيحين وغيرهما عن أبي سلمة سعيد بن يزيد قال:
>   سألت أكان النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم يصلي في نعليه؟ قال: نعم. وعند أحمد
>   وأبي داود وابن ماجه عن عمرو بن شعيب عن أبيه عن جده قال: رأيت رسول الله
>   صلى الله عليه وسلم يصلي حافياً ومنتعلاً .

[Source Arabic](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=137888)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. My mind is at ease now.

Answer (score 0):

For unclean place you can use a prayer mat or any other cloth or at least something like a newspaper. Although only it is needed that the place of genuflection not be Najis.

According to Jafari Fiqh at prayer 7 points of body should touch land and unless prayer is void. Two of these 7 points are two big toes of feet.

About the hadith saying Messenger of Allah SAWW prayed with shoes it is authentic and can be found in both Shia and Sunni hadith books. But please note it is about Arabic shoes of 1400 years ago that top of them were open and two big toes of feet could touch the land. Those Arabic shoes are something like current Sandal.

---

**Reference:**

[Why Maraji prohibit prayer with shoes while Hadith say prophet SAWW prayed with shoes?](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa29823)